# API Endpoint Change Effective 1/1/2016 Salesforce

Tags: api

I received notice of API endpoint change effective 1/1/2016. How can I know if this would affect me and what is the best way to know what all changes I have to make in my Salesforce.

So lets say I have hardcoded this www.salesforce.com in plenty of times within my code, do I need to change it everywhere manually or is there a better way?

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

---

Knowledge Article [www.salesforce.com API Endpoint Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=www-salesforce-com-API-Endpoint-Retirement&language=en_US)

Text from the **www.salesforce.com API endpoint will be retired January 1** email.

> ## Product & Service Notification
>
> As an admin of a Salesforce org, we want to notify you of an important change to the availability and support of `www.salesforce.com` as an API endpoint.
>
> **What is changing?**
>   Currently, customers can use `www.salesforce.com` as an API endpoint that will route them to the correct instance. As of January 1, 2016, the internal routing will be retired, and any API endpoints will need to be changed if from `www.salesforce.com` to `https://login.salesforce.com`.
>
> ***Note:*** This only applies to API traffic; logging in from a browser by clicking “login” will still work.
>
> **Why are we retiring the internal routing?**
>   This change is to ensure we focus our development efforts on delivering better performance and higher availability on the dedicated API endpoints.
>
> **What action do I need to take?**
>   Update your integrations to replace `www.salesforce.com` with `https://login.salesforce.com`, as the official endpoint for the Salesforce API.
>
> Please see the [Best Practices When Referencing Server Endpoints](http://click.mail.salesforce.com/?qs=23a2344704b2431610409b796725faff3755db3001110f7d2f8ad321a19be4398fd910ad4b562611) article.
>
> **What will happen if I do not take action?**
>   The API will no longer function, and your API calls will result in a “404 (Page Not Found)” error.
>
> **How can I get more information?**
>   For additional questions, you can open a case with Customer Support via the Help & Training portal.
>
> For an overview of our philosophy on retiring functionality, please click [here](http://click.mail.salesforce.com/?qs=88c1740efc599b541f60e6619d7a9a4fc63dcc87a8131ec9cb733a0c91cfb2f9110c9b328ca9e67d).
>
> *Any unreleased services or features referenced in this or other press releases or public statements are not currently available and may not be delivered on time or at all. Customers who purchase Salesforce applications should make their purchase decisions based upon features that are currently available.*

Answer (score 10):

**Short Answer**

If you're not sure then search for "www.salesforce.com" and see what you find. If you find it, replace it.

**Longer Answer**

This is primarily a warning for those integrating with Salesforce, so yes, if you have code that's referencing `www.salesforce.com` as part of an authentication request for example, then you would need to change your code and correctly choose `test.salesforce.com` or `login.salesforce.com` based on whether the user is trying to log in to a sandbox or other org.

If your only code is in Apex, then I highly doubt you have any references, and chances are if you've used any of the official SDKs from the last 5 years you wouldn't do so either.

As for having to replace it that would depend on your IDE or similar. Most tools offer a global search and replace, or you could use a command-line utility such as `sed`.

Comment: You should also be able to check the Login History table to verify if any logins are coming from www.salesforce.com. If nothing shows up in the last six months, you're presumably good to go.

Comment: Looking back through old versions of the Partner API WSDL, it looks like they changed from `www.salesforce.com` to `login.salesforce.com` somewhere between v14.0 in 2009 and v19.0 in 2010. I'm missing a few WSDL versions between there to narrow it down. So if your integration was using a WSDL < v19 you will likely need to do a fix.

Comment: You would also want to investigate any changes needed to third party tools such as middleware and other integration platforms.